# Loading of concatenated bz2 files is not supported (YARN 2.2 + Pig 0.12)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I was processing a concatenated bz2 file using a pig script on top of Pig 0.12 and YARN 2.2 and got the following error message:

```
ERROR: java.io.IOException: Encountered additional bytes in the filesplit past the crc block. Loading of concatenated bz2 files is not supported
```

I thought YARN 2.2 should have the fix for the concatenated bz2 file handling (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6835) but not yet? Or does Pig handle bzip2 file on its own instead of relying on underlying MapReduce framework or do I need to set some parameter?

Comment: This is also related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6852

Comment: I use Pig 0.12 without YARN and I have the same problem. Have you solved this? I can process the bz2 file in a standard map/reduce, but Pig fails to do it.